# ULD adpositions

Tags: vocabulary

To familiarize myself with Latin adpositions, I tried to translate the first chapter of the Universal Language Dictionary.
I would like to find for each term the least ambiguous and most common solution.

```
from (moving out of or away from); ab? ex?
to, towards, at (moving toward); ad
at (in the same location as); in
in (located inside of); intra
outside of, exterior to; extra
above, over; supra
under, below, beneath; infra
in front of, ahead of, before (spatially); 
behind, in back of, to the rear of; pone
before, prior to, earlier than; ante
during; dum
after (later than; in the future of); post
with (accompanied by/furnished with); cum
without, with no; sine
around, encircling, surrounding; circa
between, among; inter
beyond, farther than, exceeding; ultra
near, close to; juxta
on (resting on; touching the top or other surface of); 
across (at the other side of; to the other side of); trans
through; per
about (pertaining to; on the topic of); de
because of, due to; propter
by means of, via, per, with (using; through instrumentality of); via? per?
except for, apart from, excluding; nisi
for (to benefit; destined for; for the purpose of); ut
for (in exchange for); 
instead of, rather than; 
like, similar to; sicut
of (belonging to; associated with; = genitive); de
of (containing the measured quantity: "two liters of water"); de
than, compared to; quam
```

What did you think of my work? What would you have chosen?

Answer (score 1):

What is expressed by a preposition in English may or may not be expressed by a preposition in Latin.
And the same holds for many kinds of words, not just prepositions.
To give examples:

- "By means of, via, per, with (using; through instrumentality of)" is often best translated by the ablative case. The preposition *cum* can be used, but a plain ablative is more common in my experience.
- "Because of, due to" can be translated as *causa*, requiring a genitive. While you can read it as "for the reason of", you could also analyze *causa* as a postposition.
- Translating an English preposition as the Latin *in* is not quite enough. The *in* with accusative is different from the *in* with ablative, so you should specify the cases needed.
- Many things can be expressed by cases (and confusingly many by a plain ablative).
  I think the closest counterpart to "for (to benefit; destined for; for the purpose of)" is the dative case.

I wouldn't try to polish the list further, as such a list will necessarily omit many essential aspects of the language.
Some things are expressed by certain structures instead of certain words, and that can be hard to communicate.

> What would you have chosen?

To answer your question, I would have added more details on usage and described options that are not expressed by a single word.